# Mysql: comparison two SELECT expression

Tags: mysql, laravel, select, comparison

I'm trying to compare two `select` expression in one statement , each select statement has its own `join` and `where` clauses  :

expression 1 :

```
     select max(table1.created_at) from table1 join ...... where ...
```

expression 2 :

```
     select max(table2.created_at) from table2 join ...... where ...
```

how can i implement it in a mysql statement and then compare their results using greater than `>` operator like this pseudocode:

```
... exists ( expression1 > expression2)
```

Comment: Can you clue us in what your final query should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (select max(table1.created_at) from table1 join ... where ...) >
        (select max(table2.created_at) from table2 join ... where ...)
    THEN 'First max is greater.'
    ELSE 'Second max is greater.'
    END
```